# Divide data frame in three subframes based on values

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below. I would like to divide this into three submatrices bases on the average row.values. Basically I need to first calculate the average row.value and then divide the data frame based on the `ID` and the average row.value. Any ways to do this directly in one command?

dput(head(matrix_cpm_spike_norm_mature,6))

```
structure(c(3.60338983255681, 2.60614455986074, 7.38026015357423, 
0.485930325361538, 10.0728954273074, 11.2022336797709, 2.3081852592818, 
1.92925594571705, 4.42105830784866, 1.97655358070322, 11.4414272084792, 
10.5245987429194, 3.79928941804137, 1.43988964742944, 2.43182718729225, 
1.85054706660746, 10.6157635199152, 9.93246596282924, 1.76499400158053, 
0.867000595584972, 4.17937486393757, 1.62313934970233, 10.9760540633484, 
11.4384402909535, 3.12565733850373, 1.02306009758869, 6.15822532096255, 
1.45585403170949, 11.1021517437179, 10.9107307780349, 1.84965418527454, 
1.57953239648466, 3.92960542264649, 0.968010692772174, 11.0236055961936, 
10.5913003928287, 4.16812971357324, 2.58284099400479, 5.77874217548982, 
2.71612416959378, 11.6945755132658, 12.2125038706251, 2.28044423317132, 
2.28044423317132, 4.20181017967427, 1.93489752637374, 12.0201280590592, 
11.4757936894966, 3.29573463740003, 3.1840621322311, 5.6701373082146, 
1.96630490538038, 10.7374381660113, 13.2995125381539, 2.91175170429137, 
2.1569190504634, 5.20328658455966, 2.1569190504634, 10.2217040585341, 
9.83559070490264, 3.93309437957696, 2.51818736936141, 7.40221631369804, 
0.335828139281744, 10.56613413102, 10.6619866025163, 2.27796568023663, 
1.66056419670379, 5.29496497910422, 0.699488415484219, 10.310084339381, 
9.75424847574386, 3.64268206121968, 2.37908914926602, 8.24035280411754, 
1.86474527822428, 8.96352397286089, 10.2227828989983, 2.33835251965787, 
2.06871044842623, 4.5954355631791, 1.01279126170234, 12.3601973455172, 
11.4656151558222, 2.44441563566059, 2.40421119777587, 6.02973594460351, 
1.52508878726709, 10.4309455175175, 9.04837239279591, 2.19268157249804, 
1.24045869709133, 3.09706859211401, 1.13115919913948, 10.7933496311904, 
9.9695518430138, 2.92171136565383, 0.408245399247249, 2.04506253637125, 
1.21781706285458, 11.799265629373, 10.0589147547578, 2.01873582708745, 
1.46069392909814, 3.53893363843314, 1.196243674246, 11.337876323565, 
11.2124904638672, 2.52480547770426, 1.46864391283124, 4.93028527141748, 
0.732496016009805, 10.1639221283662, 9.76884595465318, 1.44174154410475, 
1.64024858387856, 5.63721432238654, 1.72991175679785, 11.1211504054224, 
10.6024617121637, 3.22964454373919, 1.02206068958127, 6.97852650980799, 
1.30645573502801, 12.8991256257565, 13.0000814142899, 2.826661275181, 
1.2548377150201, 4.36474368941959, 2.12408033247534, 12.4705231651432, 
11.9618071621679, 2.69847153335308, 2.27631143253466, 4.20951126623905, 
-0.0664422382974684, 8.98849795367716, 9.41468863016541, 2.43225940352207, 
2.09595624532069, 4.63715429950104, 1.25491429244567, 10.9872971587847, 
10.4925408800726, 3.45374293794281, 3.13429367766325, 7.39158804595222, 
1.54024232057877, 10.8542522087055, 10.6155963202093, 2.69223465587794, 
0.809912072570472, 4.64506635251942, 1.6137442296552, 11.418571423468, 
12.2726701702859, 2.77267844825925, 1.78512859921307, 9.14121538410264, 
-4.43688074939158, 9.73718972990295, 10.2957742347039, 1.49118640848005, 
1.5813150312641, 4.0667005226673, 0.59204571815906, 10.0375004920899, 
9.54533950930523, 2.16345862609174, 3.05436004610877, 8.07790690254631, 
1.79368307261622, 12.3560914214054, 13.0051227140041, 2.58124788178095, 
1.88617681546547, 2.73360657353678, 1.77592657048602, 10.9528780864007, 
10.4348473225329, 3.00497812997592, 1.7631510316129, 5.90700548290542, 
0.877605937609275, 9.87041660889873, 9.7614993662457, 2.05885671172016, 
1.76410360006183, 6.3570619407495, 1.76410360006183, 11.685705297838, 
11.3602560106241, 2.82800833596723, 2.03247959283134, 6.95870308054991, 
1.27136597104121, 10.8372565515699, 9.81173432822107, 2.98238612294936, 
1.83072752194121, 5.68689117080157, 1.16721273421709, 12.1340028664354, 
11.3680995516162, 3.39653560487816, 2.69687166650826, 6.48412064518055, 
1.29454179328719, 10.0028066556529, 10.512440462176, 1.4596941835747, 
0.727974609981551, 3.88239656448561, 0.800353161112983, 10.6363990565411, 
10.1243371999547, 3.3438733844774, 0.697114163823588, 8.47892011973568, 
0.697114163823588, 10.6855866660417, 10.6118837404499, 2.13674190430653, 
1.1527414454512, 4.18464270261989, 1.27853746250223, 10.7320904309318, 
9.89189546554829, 3.823237482187, 0.874031743370891, 1.95508453030069, 
1.87846554046761, 9.88713195004868, 9.86183499157279, 2.53517059781643, 
0.728446508864785, 3.50839578521561, 1.9965292874828, 10.9487017925789, 
10.9382935538901, 2.62649833974985, 1.92098108152647, 3.36108007152541, 
0.488100205530239, 10.4894419819966, 10.2226664777547, 1.33967056255352, 
0.0917001628908314, 3.81741552255672, 2.03856822618478, 12.2392733147047, 
11.4938478602584, 3.25046552747648, 1.48275456354609, 4.81128734606174, 
1.96154924623549, 12.1358994156854, 11.4729501435715, 2.22982247734829, 
1.68173260626794, 5.2904025048379, 1.68173260626794, 11.5137150099059, 
11.010850144881, 3.91979174751635, 2.17257846100131, 3.53963311590271, 
1.6107186758943, 11.4951784786694, 10.1260992493434, 2.35254220581856, 
1.26444532526964, 4.6646553023283, 1.17529994013973, 10.9857870198993, 
10.5814974795421, 3.75054671795939, 3.03029499770489, 9.00153489042535, 
3.27015511904915, 11.5616951026666, 10.6545660172833, 2.18325656314713, 
1.50344897782345, 3.97329240591904, 1.50344897782345, 11.3467527232018, 
10.707768513033, 2.7932432629389, 1.70473241476131, 5.05340701550577, 
0.547092257741687, 11.7624630621943, 9.91053139355945, 2.80574376605516, 
1.63874222935751, 3.92143952780207, 1.834040048536, 11.4458009229089, 
10.9155922874574, 2.81245930319929, 1.47154823046698, 4.17913709197299, 
0.836392585913434, 12.5796307717185, 11.6787505410903, 1.7257545501894, 
0.949499417203444, 5.34316953950321, 1.63528985628147, 12.2668256759477, 
11.696888238442, 2.43827755616949, 1.81088892324984, 5.13790770293989, 
1.62918292819459, 10.2635519811317, 10.3028832599596, 2.07789375455372, 
1.08266801489579, 3.36924723755809, 0.361290751749976, 9.978530962904, 
9.62993954501451, 3.46479867592192, 2.12156177109216, 8.78601850725548, 
1.28447344131806, 11.5362902737332, 11.569001443705, 1.88432186226604, 
0.738852102905189, 3.93512805821853, 2.28505136817535, 12.2366325701317, 
11.5419247012961, 2.72781971767877, 0.981047395388437, 2.42660975369917, 
1.39151946304238, 9.47444971798845, 10.1389766220257, 1.9620421090479, 
1.31100308652463, 3.9625997590393, 1.31100308652463, 11.0538785110822, 
10.5756552873608, 2.24522309004463, 1.98668802513104, 4.91591774317019, 
1.41382278476808, 10.9307830177181, 9.75061291019652, 2.89312477978526, 
1.41138577836645, 5.3114727278592, 1.18511963455519, 12.8070122897496, 
11.9900344090709, 3.27111851368705, 0.108008163568448, 3.27111851368705, 
1.04663775582004, 10.5015959502624, 10.9439135408891, 1.96611160593682, 
1.75218878170152, 1.96611160593682, -0.675585494894112, 11.1733364353258, 
10.5537870233171, 2.76365773789404, 2.24622484994411, 4.82500775257594, 
0.859189165848259, 11.3729184708685, 10.4792280890542, 2.2746810191026, 
1.26862765095299, 3.1182053649793, 1.35619562745757, 11.541422194603, 
11.0876007441211, 2.93955281780494, 2.41792430951958, 7.43488775671718, 
1.59455665002896, 10.8522501620988, 10.7066940648954, 2.56175708272954, 
1.63789352792862, 5.62616733093608, 1.77321879142546, 11.5341769241796, 
11.3614738869516, 3.52512139810446, 2.04455677275519, 9.07892025450834, 
1.80422229584867, 12.2658423589039, 12.7955854152128, 2.41662572851679, 
0.739356302189606, 6.58079778253096, 2.2056509250739, 11.4453206203817, 
11.2577755286648, 4.43488006430324, 2.47577649074622, 7.97026648668841, 
2.47577649074622, 10.5347452823169, 10.9336199647057, 0.253851439446271, 
1.33349021364545, 1.90668843852765, 1.38668924767966, 11.529988569981, 
9.68152140791945, 2.69321031115829, 1.69780604669796, 9.9826122018356, 
-0.0693106968443571, 11.2474341893491, 10.2586104182553, 2.30251678501683, 
1.67135129150304, 5.1970813744178, 1.88064524158918, 11.4072019068968, 
10.9762764532365, 2.73053313404777, 2.92486117981077, 9.751901699517, 
2.31573050368619, 11.0745724079847, 11.5397308498818, 1.85114298699175, 
1.74446232598571, 4.67405729933025, 1.36771765795199, 11.1449736215866, 
10.6467965079355, 3.12408501589049, 2.00482310148083, 4.90897925267742, 
0.753058050023766, 10.3589506698824, 10.3513173985724, 2.72147165969401, 
1.46186080167698, 3.9354821726169, 1.23699756995357, 11.1881701541595, 
10.931341142772, 2.99260441125988, 2.23826963603629, 3.87458928218141, 
0.65507014009726, 9.74342426391136, 10.8918928191143, 2.78046014914365, 
0.505490227190171, 4.43327034269568, 1.9329054288394, 11.6078716913683, 
10.9011106771378, 2.92822672503857, 1.76286882344236, 6.82012516033837, 
1.49833750295022, 9.57121023826284, 8.39324323219324, 2.81052780333747, 
1.40588646539131, 3.18875457138522, 1.18481091851206, 11.462231229116, 
10.5770583597432, 3.30911666206261, 1.33469191841737, 4.96029091396055, 
2.17413398672633, 10.5583178628059, 10.0329059364534, 1.88186145438922, 
0.989773711428552, 5.0108103947152, 0.769365496730378, 11.7867744116038, 
11.2871021676365, 2.88127273360004, 1.87947399714945, 2.88127273360004, 
1.92593791384916, 9.46125879965226, 9.29462968277333, 2.36391085778722, 
1.74079268896779, 3.93604270788606, 1.34641095936402, 10.2068762533305, 
10.0118036485061, 2.57361661875718, 2.03528106162882, 4.33420919282757, 
1.1624557079541, 11.0754175076428, 11.0622083554009, 1.93155319127651, 
1.52032894976282, 4.46324520367219, 1.52032894976282, 11.3476141375944, 
10.4138620742203, 3.85081675794147, 2.74371623100224, 1.11770920823725, 
1.98482146279348, 12.566434472332, 11.9424300470872, 2.53925962537711, 
1.48382075377967, 4.87249055114745, 1.07284442662947, 11.7111768375923, 
11.5795125663534, 2.15535566170556, 1.6234973786264, 7.72868868952004, 
0.562556076894618, 9.85480133708155, 9.92934562704339, 2.54728578873058, 
1.8265104903494, 3.76801234500258, 1.2821466213423, 11.2568527058396, 
10.8343412926481, 3.05211979795212, 0.152264838074353, 2.54493306112919, 
1.77792835724608, 11.5338955198532, 9.97573017264385, 2.42059823105591, 
0.60936602148068, 3.12812928480832, 1.14355342605761, 11.5524961118039, 
10.5285363661307), .Dim = c(6L, 92L), .Dimnames = list(c("hsa-miR-671-5p", 
"hsa-miR-3909", "hsa-miR-1247-5p", "hsa-miR-628-3p", "hsa-miR-23b-3p", 
"hsa-miR-127-3p"), c("100G", "100R", "106G", "106R", "122G", 
"122R", "124G", "124R", "126G", "126R", "134G", "134R", "141G", 
"141R", "167G", "167R", "185G", "185R", "192G", "192R", "235G", 
"235R", "239G", "239R", "243G", "243R", "246G", "246R", "261G", 
"261R", "267G", "267R", "26G", "26R", "270G", "270R", "279G", 
"279R", "299G", "299R", "301G", "301R", "305G", "305R", "342G", 
"342R", "350G", "350R", "356G", "356R", "35G", "35R", "361G", 
"361R", "366G", "366R", "367G", "367R", "377G", "377R", "379G", 
"379R", "388G", "388R", "400G", "400R", "402G", "402R", "46G", 
"46R", "48G", "48R", "55G", "55R", "57G", "57R", "60G", "60R", 
"68G", "68R", "70G", "70R", "73G", "73R", "77G", "77R", "82G", 
"82R", "93G", "93R", "94G", "94R")))
```

Comment: Try `df2 <- df1; df2[-1] <- df1[-1]/rowMeans(df1[-1])[row(df1[-1])]`

Comment: Rather than posting the result of `print(df)`, post the result of `dput(df)`. It's much easier for us to import.

Comment: What is the expected output?  I thought you want to divide the columns by the `rowMeans`

Comment: Sorry, I want three separate data frames. The first should have the rows with the highest rowMeans, the second should have the rows with the medium rowMeans and the last should have the rows with the lowest rowMeans

Comment: I think you need `cut` here. i.e `v1 <- rowMeans(df1[-1]); v2 <- cut(v1, breaks=3)` and then `split` by `v2`

Comment: importing the `dput(...)` is working for me (except that it's a matrix, not a data.frame).

Comment: As @jlhoward mentioned, by sourcing, I was able to get the `matrix`.  There is no ID column, so it is just `v1 <- rowMeans(m1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we need `cut` to `split` up the rows of the `matrix` after getting the `rowMeans`

```
 v1 <- rowMeans(m1)
 v2 <- cut(v1, breaks=3)
 v2
 #[1] (5.52,8.48] (11.4,14.4] (5.52,8.48] (11.4,14.4] (5.52,8.48] (5.52,8.48]
 #Levels: (5.52,8.48] (8.48,11.4] (11.4,14.4]
```

We `split` the sequence of rows of the matrix ('m1') by 'v2', subset the rows of 'm1' based on the row index to create a `list` of 3 matrices.

```
 lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(m1), v2), function(i) m1[i,])
```

Comment: This is a good way of doing this in base R (no other packages needed). IF there were many more splits (eg thousands), `split()` becomes inefficient.

Comment: @PaulJames `split` is still very efficient compared to `==` in subsetting datasets in a list.  I am not sure how many `split`s the OP has in his dataset, but based on the example, 3 is reasonably quick.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a different approach to grouping by row-means. This uses kmeans clustering on the row-means to divide based on the closeness of the values. I think this is more in line with your description "low", "med", "high".

Your data set as provided is a matrix with 6 rows and 96 columns (the ID's are in the row.names.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rownames(df),df)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rm:=rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols=2:ncol(df), by=ID]
df[,grp:=kmeans(rm, centers=3)$cluster]
df[,list(ID,rm,grp)]
#               ID        rm grp
# 1: hsa-let-7a-3p  5.819544   1
# 2: hsa-let-7a-5p 14.396980   3
# 3: hsa-let-7b-3p  5.526127   1
# 4: hsa-let-7b-5p 11.548722   3
# 5: hsa-let-7c-5p  7.881395   2
# 6: hsa-let-7d-3p  6.368912   1

result <- split(df,df$grp)   # split into 3 data.tables based on group
```

You can see that 5.5, 5.8, and 6.3 are in the first group, 7.9 is in the second group, and 11.5 and 14.4 are in the 3rd group.

Comment: A doubt, wouldn't the `kmeans` assignment of index is `random`?  I was trying to do the same with `library(Hmisc); cut2(v1, g=3)`, but the index seemed to be changing.

Comment: @akrun The initial assignment of cluster centers is random, so the cluster numbers can be in any order, but I don't see why that is a problem. The point is to divide the data set based on "low", "medium" and "high" row-means.

Comment: @jhoward I didn't mean that it is a problem.  Just wanted to know if it is random order